# use paste it with on a freezed union class

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, provider

How to use paste it with on a freezed union class, that implements a specific mixin with provider or bloc. want to implements multiple mixin in bloc class.
and I have an object of type Example , how can I check if the example implements Geographicarea and copy it with Interfacespecific properties?

```
`var dpmData= Dpm.city();

//How to check if this instance implements GeographicArea and call copyWith with a GeographicArea specific parameter?

dpmDaata= dpmData.copyWith(population: 20000);`
```